# How do I remove a list item from a dict value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a host dict that contains a hostname key, and list values. I would like to be able to remove any item of fruit_ from the list of each value.

```
host = { 
  'abc.com': ['fruit_apple', 'fruit_orange', 'veg_carrots'], 
  '123.com': None, 
  'foo.com': ['fruit_tomatoes', 'veg_potatoes']
}

for v in host.values():
  if v is not None:
    for x in v:
      try:
        # creating my filter
        if x.startswith('fruit_'):
        # if x finds my search, get, or remove from list value
         host(or host.value()?).get/remove(x)# this is where i'm stuck
        print(hr.values(#call position here?)) # prove it
      except:
        pass
```

I'm stuck around the commented area, I feel like I'm missing another iteration (new list somewhere?), or maybe I'm not understanding how to write the list value back. Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: In your example `if v is not None:` will always be `True`. you probably knew that already

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I guess you have a `None` in the values of `host` that isn't posted?. I just wanted to make sure that you didn't think it would catch `[None]`

Comment: I guess I should update that, ''123.com': [ None ], ' should probbly read '123.com': None, not in a list.

Comment: No problem, I didn't mean to nit pick, I guess you did already know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to filter items from a list is to use list comprehension with a filtering condition and create a new list, like this.

```
host = {
    'abc.com': ['fruit_apple', 'fruit_orange', 'veg_carrots'],
    '123.com': [None],
    '456.com': None,
    'foo.com': ['fruit_tomatoes', 'veg_potatoes']
}


def reconstruct_list(vs):
    return vs if vs is None else [
        v for v in vs if v is None or not v.startswith('fruit_')
    ]


print({k: reconstruct_list(vs) for k, vs in host.items()})
```

**Output**

```
{'abc.com': ['veg_carrots'], '123.com': [None], '456.com': None, 'foo.com': ['veg_potatoes']}
```

In this particular case, individual values of the lists are filtered and a new dictionary object is created with dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @hobbes I think your data has `None` as a value instead of `[None]` in some cases. Is that correct?

Comment: that is correct, i've made the update above. it should have not been in a list.

Comment: @hobbes I updated the answer to fit both the `None` cases. Its just ignoring `None` from the filtering.

Comment: Wow, that did it, thank you! I will need to take some time to digest that list comprehension, I understand a bit of it, but still grasping on breaking it down into chunks, into an order of operation.

Comment: @hobbes Start with [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

What about rebuilding the dictionary with a dict comprehension:

```
>>> host = { 
  'abc.com': ['fruit_apple', 'fruit_orange', 'veg_carrots'], 
  '123.com': [None] , 
  'foo.com': ['fruit_tomatoes', 'veg_potatoes']
}

>>> {k: [x for x in v if not str(x).startswith('fruit_') or not x] for k, v in host.items()}
{'abc.com': ['veg_carrots'], '123.com': [None], 'foo.com': ['veg_potatoes']}
```

Or if `'123.com'` has just `None` as a value, you can do this:

```
>>> host = { 
  'abc.com': ['fruit_apple', 'fruit_orange', 'veg_carrots'], 
  '123.com': None , 
  'foo.com': ['fruit_tomatoes', 'veg_potatoes']
}

>>> {k: v if not v else [x for x in v if not x.startswith('fruit_')] for k, v in host.items()}
{'abc.com': ['veg_carrots'], '123.com': None, 'foo.com': ['veg_potatoes']}
```

Comment: also correct, thank you. this is nice to compare to when breaking it down your examples, and the one posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
host = {
  'abc.com': ['fruit_apple', 'fruit_orange', 'veg_carrots'],
  '123.com': None,
  'foo.com': ['fruit_tomatoes', 'veg_potatoes']
}


print({i:[k for k in j if not k.startswith('fruit_')] if j!=None  else None for i,j in host.items() })
```

But if there is no None then you can try this interesting approach:

```
print(dict(map(lambda z,y:(z,list(filter(lambda x:not x.startswith('fruit_'),host[y]))),host,host)))
```